# Facing issue while upgrading the react-native version of the project from"0.66.3" to "0.72.6"

Tags: react-native

I am trying to upgrade my project's react-native version but facing with a build issue in android.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\SanjanaV\Documents\stackyon-mobile\android\app\build.gradle' line: 92
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not read script 'C:\Users\SanjanaV\Documents\stackyon-mobile\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' as it does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion i

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
  error Failed to install the app.